# foreach two arrays iteration in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Ok, so I already searched around and I can't seem to get an answer, I two arrays, one for questions and one for answers, I'm trying to list each question and their answers using nested foreach, it does list the questions correctly but i get the answers of the first question to all of the questions, here's my code:

```
<?php foreach($questions as $question): ?>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;"><?=$id?> <?=$question['question']?></p>
    <?php if($question['type'] == 1): ?>
        <?php foreach($answers as $id => $answer):?>
            <input type="radio" name="<?=$answer['ans_id']?>" value="<?=$answer['points']?>"> <?=$answer['answers']?><br />
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <br />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <hr>
    <?php $id++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit:

Here's a print_r of the arrays:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [type] => 1
    [question] => ¿Te enojas facilmente?
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 1
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => Si, soy impulsivo y explosivo
    [points] => 1
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 2
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => No, soy bien pacifico
    [points] => 5
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 3
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => No, soy bien pacifico
    [points] => 5
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [type] => 1
    [question] => ¿Cuantos amigos tienes?
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 1
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => Si, soy impulsivo y explosivo
    [points] => 1
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 2
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => No, soy bien pacifico
    [points] => 5
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 3
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => No, soy bien pacifico
    [points] => 5
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [type] => 1
    [question] => ¿cuantas veces?
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 1
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => Si, soy impulsivo y explosivo
    [points] => 1
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 2
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => No, soy bien pacifico
    [points] => 5
)
Array
(
    [ans_id] => 3
    [question_id] => 1
    [quiz_id] => 1
    [answers] => No, soy bien pacifico
    [points] => 5
)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: show us your array structure

Comment: Need to know the structure of your two array.

Comment: I just added the arrays printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array structure should be like this

```
            <?php
                $question = array(
                    'qid1' => 'question 1?'
                    'qid2' => 'question 2?'
                    //...
                );

                $answer = array(
                    'qid1' => array(
                            'ansid-1' => 'answer for q  1 1'
                            'ansid-2' => 'answer for q  1 2'
                            'ansid-3' => 'answer for q  1 3'
                            'ansid-4' => 'answer for q  1 4'
                            ),
                    'qid2' => array(
                            'ansid-5' => 'answer for q  2 1'
                            'ansid-6' => 'answer for q  2 2'
                            'ansid-7' => 'answer for q  2 3'
                            'ansid-8' => 'answer for q  2 4'
                            )
                )

                foreach( $question $qid=>$q){
                    // + question related html start

                        foreach($answer[$qid] as $answer_id => $answer){
                            // + answer related html
                        }

                    // + question related html end
                }

            ?>
```

I think this will help you

Comment: so, you're saying I need to arrange the structure that way in order for it to function?

Comment: Yes, I think that will be better.

Comment: Dude sorry, thanks! It did helped me rearrange my stuff but the problem was my query all along lol

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
<?php
$First = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$Second = array('1', '2', '3', '4');

for ($indx = 0 ; $indx < count($First); $indx ++) {
echo $First[$indx] . $Second[$indx];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```